# grep md5has from java command

Tags: java, bash, grep, md5

I have tried many combinations, but I can't get a specific string from a Java command to generate an md5 hash:

```
java -cp /var/lib/rundeck/bootstrap/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin outsideit.net | grep -o "^MD5"
outsideit.net
OBF:1y0q1w9b1xtx1l1g155w1toa1t331tok1wui1kxm1xtl1w8f1y10
MD5:a7da14229ea147aaa364e503947cbe35
CRYPT:adiwf3pJ9m8Vw
```

Whichever grep statement I try it always outputs the above.

Comment: It probably outputs to stderr. Add `2>&1` to the Java side

Comment: Perhaps your program is writing to `System.err`, not `System.out`, so the pipe to `grep` is not seeing anything?

Comment: Seems like it does indeed output to stderr. Adding 2>&1 to end of the Java command did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the java command throws the output as stderr, the bash will not be able to grep it untill you specify "&> >(grep MD5)" instead of " | grep ". The below command show work for you.

`java -cp /var/lib/rundeck/bootstrap/jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin outsideit.net &> >(grep MD5)`